# Apache site root for development directories on localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I think I'm missing something and don't think I really understand how rewriteBase works.

The problem I have is that I have a production site where the site is in the root directory yet I have my development site in a localhost subdirectory. Eg **http://www.sitename.com/** vs **http://localhost/sitename/**

If I have for example an images folder I want to reference the images from the site root by using the initial slash in the href. Eg  Using a relative href (without the initial slash) is not an option. This will work on the production site but the development site is looking for **http://localhost/images/imagename.jpg** instead of **http://localhost/*sitename*/images/imagename.jpg**

So I thought all I needed to do was setup the following in my .htaccess file to force the site root to my subdomain within the development environment:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sitename
```

But this still uses localhost as the site root instead of localhost/sitename.

Can anyone please give me some pointers?

-------------------------EDIT---------------------------

I stopped trying to do this in the .htaccess file and tried to just use the html  command but this also didn't work.

In the end I set up Virtual Hosts in Apache on the local server but it seems like such an awful lot of overkill to just change the site root. I'm also concerned that other developers on the LAN network won't be able to access the site properly via the virtual host.

I'm really needing some 'best practice' advice please on setting up a workable development environment in WAMP.

Comment: I had to do large modification on a site from a server that had 8 sites (virtual hosts), so I copied the site to another directory, and added a new virtual host for that directory (and a new subdomain). Don't think it's an overkill, In my case was the best way of simulating a development server.

Comment: Over time we have been setting up virtual hosts for all our web development projects. Since writing the OP it has become pretty much our standard practise.

Comment: It's a good practice.  To make the dev site available to others, wildcard DNS comes in handy.  If you had a host called dev01.example,com, just have *.dev01.example.com point there.  Then when you need a devsite for project "foo", you just set up a virtualhost for foo.dev01.example.com, and avoid having to touch DNS or hostsfiles.

Comment: @timdev : +1 for the wilcard DNS, It is simpler, especialy when you don't own the DNS server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteBase` alone, basically, tells Apache where to apply the `RewriteRule`s. Here you don't have any. By the way, you can either remove the RewriteBase directive altogether, or change it to:

```
RewriteBase /
```

The following two lines should get it to work for your development environment **only**:

```
RewriteCond %{ REQUEST_FILENAME } !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /sitename/$1 [L,QSA]
```

These two directives mean: "if the requested file does not exist (-f), and only in that case, rewrite the url prepending `/sitename/` to the requested URI (`$1`)".

For more info you can have a look at [Apache mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [Apache URL rewriting guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).